# Table cell sometimes not updated when using two type of cells in a table and every cell are duplicated behind in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First, please look at this screenshot:
[image]

This screenshot is from Debug View Hierarchy in Xcode.

I was going to show two types of cells in a table.
- First row is post cell,
- From the second are the comment cells

I used 2 sections in this table, 1st section for post cell (1 row) and second section for comment cells(n rows).

Post cell and comment cell has UILabels, ImageViews in it and used auto layout.

If I run the app, it looks perfectly and when I scroll up and down it seems have no issue.
But if I delete a row or change the text in the cell, it doesn't change. If I debug the values, it is set correctly.

I looked at Debug Hierarchy View and found changes are applied to the behind cells and if I delete the cell, upper cells are deleted and behind cells still exist and it looks not deleted.

If I show comment cells only, this issue is not occur and also the UITableViewCells are not duplicated.

Here are the codes for the table:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [_comments count];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == _table) {
        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"postcell";

            PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSLog(@" ===  cellForRowAtIndexPath (0,0)");
            cell.tag = indexPath.row;
            cell.index = indexPath.row;
            [cell setCellData:_postData];

            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = 0;

//            [cell setNeedsLayout];
//            [cell layoutIfNeeded];

            return cell;
        } else {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"commentcell";

            int row = (int)indexPath.row;
            CommentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            [cell setCellData:[_comments objectAtIndex:row]];
            cell.tag = indexPath.row;
            NSLog(@" === cellForRowAtIndexPath (1, %d)", row);
            //            cell.index = indexPath.row;
            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.accessoryType = 0;

//            [cell setNeedsLayout];
//            [cell layoutIfNeeded];

            if(cell == nil) {
                NSLog(@"returning nill cell at row: %d", row);
            }

            return cell;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Please help me what did I wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, probably, the `static` keyword on `NSString *CellIdentifier`. When in the scope of a method, `static` is basically a `const`.

What you should do is calculate the cell identifier on every call to this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( tableView == _table ) {
        // These 2 values are fixed, so we use static.
        // Do NOT use the same variable names (postCellIdentifier, commentsCellIdentifier)
        // on other parts of this method.
        static NSString *postCellIdentifier = @"postcell";
        static NSString *commentsCellIdentifier = @"commentscell";

        // This one is calculated every time tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is messaged
        NSString *cellIdentifier = ( indexPath.section == 0 ) ? postCellIdentifier : commentsCellIdentifier;

        // Dequeue the cell with the calculated cell identifier
        UITableView *genericCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if ( cellIdentifier == postCellIdentifier ) {
            PostTableViewCell *cell = (id) genericCell;
            // Configure your post cell
        }
        else {
            CommentsTableViewCell *cell = (id) genericCell;
            // Configure your comments cell
        }
    }

    return genericCell;
}
```

Also, note that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is **guaranteed** to always return a cell (i.e. doesn't return `nil`). It's older counterpart `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` can return `nil` and that's why, in the past, you needed to check if the cell is `nil`. That's not the case anymore with the new method.

If, for some reason, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` cannot dequeue a cell, it will raise a `NSInternalInconsistencyException` and your app will crash. This could be the case, for example, when you're dequeuing with an unregistered cell identifier.

=====

**EDIT:** Now that I re-read your question, the problem of setting a text and the text isn't changing is probably due to what queue are you using to set the text.

When you modify the UI (change texts, frames, etc.), you have to do it on the main queue (which is responsible for the UI). In other words, instead of doing:

```
someLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

You should be doing:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    someLabel.text = @"Hello";
});
```

The main question here would be: Where are you modifying those texts? Seems like the important code is the `setCellData:` method from your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: I set breakpoint when the cell is nil, but never caught so far. It seems not the main reason. And I tried remove static keyword, but error still occurs.

Comment: Try the code I wrote (and re-read the explanation... I know your cell is not `nil`).

Comment: I used the main queue already and it is not working. When I debug, texts are set correctly inside main queue block. Please consider the text are set the behind the cell(see above attached image).

Comment: Are your outlets actually connected?

Comment: Of course, it is working at first, but not working some times later

Comment: Hmm... maybe, instead of this code, it would be preferrable to see the code of your `UITableViewCell` subclasses (`PostTableViewCell` and `CommentsTableViewCell`).

Comment: Here is source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cldikxr4fxm6qpm/stackoverflow.zip?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to change

   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

to

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

How are you deleting a row or changing the text?

Comment: 1) Try setting clipToBound for your cell and it's contentView, sometimes content get mixed in next cell.
2) You should handle if cell returned from deque is nil with below code.

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}`

Comment: @user130934 - I printed error code when the cell is nil and set breakpoint, but never caught.